# How to use external (custom) package in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to replicate the soultion given here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/spark_python.html
to import external packages in pypspark. But it is failing.

My code:

spark_distro.py

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def import_my_special_package(x):
    from external_package import external
    return external.fun(x)

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext()
int_rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
int_rdd.map(lambda x: import_my_special_package(x)).collect()
```

external_package.py

```python
class external:

    def __init__(self,in):
        self.in = in

    def fun(self,in):
        return self.in*3
```

spark submit command:

```python
spark-submit \
   --master yarn \
  /path to script/spark_distro.py  \
  --py-files /path to script/external_package.py \
  1000
```

Actual Error:

```python
Actual:
  vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/home/gsurapur/pyspark_examples/spark_distro.py", line 13, in <lambda>
  File "/home/gsurapur/pyspark_examples/spark_distro.py", line 6, in import_my_special_package
ImportError: No module named external_package
```

Expected output:

```python
[3,6,9,12]
```

I tried `sc.addPyFile` option too and it is failing with same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that, in hindsight, it sounds silly, but the order of the arguments of `spark-submit` is not in general interchangeable: all Spark-related arguments, including `--py-file`, must be **before** the script to be executed:

```python
# your case:
spark-submit --master yarn-client /home/ctsats/scripts/SO/spark_distro.py --py-files /home/ctsats/scripts/SO/external_package.py
[...]
ImportError: No module named external_package

# correct usage:
spark-submit --master yarn-client --py-files /home/ctsats/scripts/SO/external_package.py /home/ctsats/scripts/SO/spark_distro.py
[...]
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Tested with your scripts modified as follows:

spark_distro.py

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def import_my_special_package(x):
    from external_package import external
    return external(x)

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext()
int_rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
print int_rdd.map(lambda x: import_my_special_package(x)).collect()
```

external_package.py

```python
def external(x):
     return x*3
```

with the modifications arguably not changing the essence of the question...

Comment: Yes. You are right. Order of the arguments was the issue. I was about to post that here and then i saw your answer. Thank you @desertnaut

Answer (score 3):

Here is the situation regarding `addPyFile`:

spark_distro2.py

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def import_my_special_package(x):
    from external_package import external
    return external(x)

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile("/home/ctsats/scripts/SO/external_package.py") # added
int_rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
print int_rdd.map(lambda x: import_my_special_package(x)).collect()
```

Test:

```python
spark-submit --master yarn-client /home/ctsats/scripts/SO/spark_distro2.py
[...]
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```