# How to pass additional modules in pyspark using Pycharm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am creating a pyspark application which is modular in nature. My code struture is like:

```
├── main.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jobs
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── logic.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── utility.py
```

I have setup a fully distributed mode of spark for dealing with large data processing.

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster(local_settings.SPARK_MASTER).setAppName(app_name) \
        .set("spark.cores.max", max_cores)
```

My start script is main.py and my project is run this script by Pycharm because I want to debug the logic behind or see the variables easily.

In `spark-submit`, we can add `--py-files` for the additional modules.
However, when I run main.py in Pycharm, the workers have an error about

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

In Pycharm, I have set the env variables below.

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6;PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6;PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/project/spark_project:$PYTHONPATH;SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
```

Even I add the project path to PYTHONPATH, it's still not found my 'src' module.

Is there any way to add additional modules when using Pycharm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use external (custom) package in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101375/how-to-use-external-custom-package-in-pyspark)

Comment: @user10938362 yes, but I'm using pycharm not spark-submit to run the script